# How do I "Get My Foot in the Door"?

Tags: fide

The title may be a little misleading. My question is, how do I become or begin to become a player who is in the FIDE system? Is there a specific process I must go to, specific tournaments, steps I must take etc. to "get my foot in the door" of the FIDE system. I'd like to play in official tournaments and all the like, but I am not sure how to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated.

You need to play in FIDE-rated events. Even playing one game would get you in the system (meaning they would be aware of your existence), but you would not be officially rated until you played at least 5 games against FIDE-rated players, during the course of 26 months, and be rated over 1000. It no longer appears as if you need and minimum score.

For more of the detailed points, check out the [FIDE Handbook here](https://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=197&view=article), specifically under section 7.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you, is there any website which contains all of the FIDE events posted that I can sign up for? Or all they all already contained in the FIDE website?

Comment: On FIDE.com's home page, there are links by continent.

Comment: @NorbertTanacs What country are you in?

Comment: This information is false. The minimum number of games is 5 not 9 and the minimum score is 0.5 not 1. The best answer to the previous version of this question gives more accurate information.

Comment: Brian, you are correct. I went by old information, and trusted that second look too much. Had I read article 7 more closely, it said what you originally answered. I saw that, but was still swayed by that second link for some reason.

Comment: Brian, it looks like they dropped the minimum .5 score. Am I missing something?

Comment: @David I'm in Canada